# How to chnage/bind input source from multiple input to output in ffmpeg without map option?

Tags: dictionary, ffmpeg

I want to apply custom input from multiple input to output with run time in FFmpeg. I can able to change input source runtime in FFmpeg. Any one have the idea for that?

Comment: Need more specific details. Not generally possible,except in limited circumstances..

Comment: Thanks for reply @Gyan.
Details : I have two input live source and want to change or switch run time. Means my output stream have video what we have selected run time. Is there any way that we can modify FFmpeg code and able to change input source ? or any way to change programs OR its streams run time form input source?